# How to create draggable and editable list items using @angular/cdk?

Tags: angular, typescript, contenteditable, angular-cdk

I'm trying to create a horizontal draggable list with items that should be editable. For that I'm using the cdk package without material and with the attribute  `[contentEditable]='true'`. But the items are not editable. How do I get it working?

```
<div cdkDropList [cdkDropListOrientation]="'horizontal'" class="namingConventionDragDrop"
     (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of resultConvention; let i = index;">
        <div cdkDrag class="pop naming-placeholder" *ngIf="item.type === 'placeholder'">
                {{item.value}}
            <fa-icon (click)="remove(i)" icon="times-circle"></fa-icon>
        </div>
        <div cdkDrag class="pop" *ngIf="item.type === 'text'
           [contentEditable]="true" (click)="onItemClick($event)">
                {{item.value}}
            <fa-icon (click)="remove(i)" icon="times-circle"></fa-icon>
        </div>
        <div class="pop deactivated" *ngIf="item.type === 'extension'">
            {{item.value}}
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
<div class="naming-convention preview">
    <span>Preview:</span>
    {{preview}}
</div>
```

Because I thought it has something to do with focus, I added a focus() call:

```
onItemClick(event) {
    event.target.focus();
}
```

Preview of the frontend. The user should be able to edit items that are of type "text":

[image: Preview of the frontend. The user should be able to drag & drop items and to edit items of type "text" (e.g. the first one)]

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61128879/5214911) for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular CDK seems to absorb left click events. One option is to use right click to edit.