# contenteditable is not working with cdkDrag

Tags: contenteditable, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I am trying to use a div element tag and make it behave as a textarea with css.

```
#textarea {
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;   ------------ card.component.css
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font: medium -moz-fixed;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    height: 28px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: both;
    width: 400px;
}

<div id="textarea" contenteditable>I look like a textarea</div>  ---- card.component.html
```

But i am using cdkDrag on my card from parent component(Category component)

```
<div cdkDrag class="col-sm-12 px-2 pb-2">
  <app-card (cardEvent)="deleteCard($event)" [card]="card">
```

I found this link [contenteditable not working properly with cdkDrag on google-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56544752/contenteditable-not-working-properly-with-cdkdrag-on-google-chrome) explaining the same, but couldn't get any answer.

Answer (score 9):

CDK's `DragRef` listens to the `mousedown` event, so you can add a `(mousedown)="$event.stopPropagation()"` handler to your `contenteditable` div to prevent that event from bubbling up to the element that has the `cdkDrag` directive on it.

edit: Here's the call site in the CDK `DragRef` code: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/drag-drop/drag-ref.ts#L775

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="custom-editable" contenteditable="true" #contentNotes (mousedown)="$event.stopPropagation()"></div>
```

its working and working good result

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by [left click mouse events being absorbed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54905884) by the `CdkDrag` directive. If you use tab to navigate to the element or right click on it, editing is possible which confirms this.

A possible solution is to set the `cdkDragDisabled` property of the `CdkDrag` directive to true like

```
<div cdkDrag [cdkDragDisabled]="some condition" ...
```

for times of the editing.

Just add the same value to `[cdkDragDisabled]` and `[contentEditable]` and you're good.